# Viewflow: AllProcessListView return empty

Tags: django-viewflow

I'm trying to use viewflow in my project but I'm having a few problems with the views that start with "All" (AllProcessListView, AllQueueListView, ecc..).
I created some custom templates for them but they always return me empty querysets, even if the specific views for a process show the correct results. Any help please? 
This is my url setup:

```
url(r'^flow_processes', AllProcessListView.as_view(), name='flow_processes'),
url(r'^flow_queues', AllQueueListView.as_view(), name='flow_queues'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AllProcessListView need to be instanciated with information how flow classes are mapped into django url namespaces in your url config ex:

https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/57eafb964c0d599fba239144e02f739c8c91bb60/tests/test_views_list.py#L14

```
views.AllProcessListView.as_view(ns_map={ListViewTestFlow: 'listviewtest'})
```